# Unable to find OraOLEDB.Oracle provider in the Linked Server Providers

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I am trying to configure a *Linked Server* in *SQL Server* to *Oracle* database. However, I am unable to find *OraOLEDB.Oracle* in the providers list of the linked servers.

Would you please guide me to find a solution to this issue ?

Thank you :)

Comment: what version of sql server, what version of Oracle?

Comment: @kevinsky SQL Server 2012, Oracle 11 g

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the [latest ODAC package](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html) from Oracle installed on the SQL Server end.  This includes an OLEDB driver.